# Should a password salt be stored in its own field in the database?

Tags: database, security, passwords

I've been doing a lot of research to determine best practices for storing passwords for a system I'm currently developing. So far, I've decided that I'm going to be using a SHA512 hash with an RNG to generate a salt for *each* password (obviously best practice against Rainbow Tables etc).

Would storing the passwords in *two* separate fields in the table be too simplistic to determine the password representation in the database (there's a `PasswordHash` field and a `PasswordSalt` field)? It may seem like security through obscurity, but I was thinking of storing the salt and the password hash together in one field concatenated together.

Would this "help" at all?

Comment: +1 Good question, I was writing my own before I stumbled upon this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it seperately.

Remember what you are protecting against: The scenario is someone gets a copy of your database and therefore can execute a rainbow-table lookup against the fields, if not salted.

It really doesn't matter if the attacker knows the salt; it's just to stop him from using pre-generated rainbow tables.

Comment: I knew the general idea, but wasn't sure if it was *really* necessary. Thanks for your input.

Comment: For the sake of optimization though, surely it would be better to store in the same field?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't really matter much. The salt doesn't give away any secrets, in fact, it helps keeping secrets. If you want to impress your database designer friends, keep it in a field of its own. If you want to impress your optimizing friends, keep it with the hash. It's a matter of style, really.

Regarding the salt; you might want to make it long enough to prevent against rainbow table attacks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables